# When connecting to an oracle cloud instance it asks me for a username and password

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I just created an instance in oracle cloud and I managed to connect to it by ssh but when completing the connection it asks me for a password and a user that I do not know, I have not set this protection at any time.

Comment: Did you look up the default username in the documentation? Did you download the certificate for the instance and configure it in your SSH client? If you're getting prompted for password then it doesn't sound like your cert is correctly configured.

Comment: @pmdba Yes, the connection to the machine is correct because if I try to connect from Cloud Shell it looks the same.

Comment: It should only prompt you for password if the ssh certificate wasn't being properly sent by your ssh client. Otherwise you should only be prompted for the username. As far as I know, the certificate is required for remote authentication.

Comment: @pmdba So... what is the user name and password?

Comment: There is no password. You must have the ssh certificate that was available for download when the instance was created. The default username is "opc" which is available in the OCI documentation.

Comment: @pmdba I reiterate, the connection is correct because it does not indicate any error, I have also used the cloud shell as a connection method and it keeps asking me to log in.

Comment: It prompts for password because that's what Linux does when no SSH key is provided. There is no password authentication option available for OCI instances. You *must* have the SSH key. If you didn't set that up during instance creation, there is no way to authenticate to the instance. This is stated explicitly in the documentation and on the instance creation screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default username for all compute instances is "opc" for Oracle Linux or "ubuntu" for Ubuntu, which is mentioned in the documentation. During instance creation you must either download the generated SSH private key or provide self-generated keys for upload to the new instance.

If you don't download the private key from Oracle or upload your own public key, then there won't be any way to connect to the instance using SSH. There is no password option. This is stated explicitly in the "Add SSH Keys" section of the "Create Compute Instance" screen when creating the instance.

OCI Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/launchinginstance.htm

> You cannot provide a public key or save the key pair that is generated
> by Oracle Cloud Infrastructure after the instance is created.

The following link describes various methods of creating SSH key pairs for use if you choose to create your own rather than download the ones provided by Oracle.

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/learn/generate_ssh_keys/index.html#introduction

Answer (score 1):

There are no password at this time.
Solution using OCI Cloud Sell:

1. Access cloud shell (developer tools icon on top right);
2. Upload SSH private key (Cloud shell menu -> upload);
3. Need to change file permission to a more restrictive access: `chmod 400 your-ssh-key-file`
4. Change Network: click expand and: Create Private Network Definition List
   -> Create -> choose VCN and subnetwork where instance was created; Create.
5. Connect instance where user is: "opc" for oracle, or "ubuntu" for ubuntu:

> ssh -i your-file-ssh-key  opc@<ip>